# Maven project wont build on windows 10

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Java maven project that builds on my Mac however when i moved it to my windows machine i get the following exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider`
I've tried restarting and reimporting and no luck. I have maven surefire version 3.0.0.M5 in my POM.xml

Comment: Do you use JUnit 5 only dependencies? Check this guide: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html Make sure the project is buildable from command line. Also try running tests from command line - what is the result?

Comment: If you use JDK 9 or higher, follow the hint https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/3159#issuecomment-703356178